# iOS Swift 5 Realm Results w/ UITableView blocks UI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm building an App based on the Realm Database. I have a overview screen with 5 UITableViews which are all powered by a Results in conjunction with a NotificationToken. So in total, I have 5 Results and 5 NotificationTokens (each with a different kind of Object).

This overview screen is displayed in the second tab of a UITabBarController. When I run the app for the first time and select the overview tab, it takes a noticeable time till the tab shows (~1s).

**What can I do to either speed up the loading time or keep the UI responsive while the Results are loaded?**

The Results load all entities of their object type. All are sorted by a "name" key path.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to either speed up the loading time or keep the UI responsive while the Results are loaded?

That depends where that time is being spent.

### 1. Large Realm file

If the Realm file is large, memory-mapping it may be a computationally-expensive operation. If this is the case, you could use [`Realm.asyncOpen(...)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:ZFC10RealmSwift5Realm9asyncOpenFT13configurationVS0_13Configuration13callbackQueueCSo13DispatchQueue8callbackFTGSqS0__GSqPs5Error___T__T_) to asynchronously open the file on a background queue, delivering the opened Realm on the given callback queue (e.g. main queue).

### 2. Large Number Of Objects

If you have a very large number of objects, perhaps you could restructure your data model to reduce that number?

For example, say you have an `isDeleted` boolean property on your model, and you manually synchronize those delete operations in your RESTful web API at a later time when your app has connectivity. Instead of keeping all those objects, you could have a new model (e.g. `WebOperation`) containing just the information you need to perform that operation rather than the full object (e.g. `{operation: 'delete', id: '1234'}`.

### 3. Computationally-Expensive Query

If either (or all) of your queries are computationally expensive, you could perform them asynchronously on a background thread. By adding a notification block to a Realm collection (e.g. a `Results`), if you don't access the `Results` synchronously, the notification block will run the query in the background, delivering the `Results` in an `.initial` notification on the originating thread only when the query has been evaluated, which offloads the query operation to a background thread, freeing up your UI thread.

### 4. Under-Optimized Query

Some queries are faster than others. Experiment with different ways to structure your query, measure and compare the results. Pick the most efficient variant.

Comment: Imagine a App where you have cars, manufacturers and colors. You want to show them side by side. Each tableview is powered by a Results as the datasource and a NotificationToken to automatically populate updates (insert/move/delete/reload). The Realm file itself is actually not that big. Lets say 100 cars, 20 manufactures and 30 colors) so I think 1 is not really the problem I guess (or could it be already the bottleneck?). The queries are "get all cars sorted by name", "get all manufacturers sorted by name", "get all colors sorted by name".

Comment: Not sure how expensive this is. I never call tableView.reload() directly but only setup the results, then the notification token and inside the token use the .initial to reload the tableview for the first time. So, hmm I'm not sure what I should do. might it be the problem, that I setup the results on the main thread?